# Getting blow alert to verify flutter installation and version in macOS?

Tags: flutter

**Alert1** - “gen_snapshot” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

**Alert2** - “idevice_id” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

Comment: I do believe that these are existing (and open) issues on the Flutter SDK. Please read more about it [here #1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50066) and [here #2](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42969). Thank you.

Comment: I am new to flutter, did not check these open issues, Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Go to System Preferences> Security & Privacy

When you click cancel to the pop up that say “gen_snapshot” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified, you should see a button that says "Allow anyway" multiple times

Click that button and you will be good.

Comment: I am not able to see that popup  on security & policy

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by accepting licenses in my case. Run:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

and accept by entering y and enter.